# Symfony 2 install SonataIntBundle date_time_object not found

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use SonataIntBundle to translate the twig datetime.

I added in my composer.json: 
    `"sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master"`

AppKernel.php: 
    `new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),`

config:tml:
    `sonata_intl:
        timezone:
            default: Europe/Paris
            locales:
                fr:    Europe/Paris
                en:    Europe/London`

I try the code:
   `{{ date_time_object | format_datetime(null, 'fr', 'Europe/Paris',constant('IntlDateFormatter::LONG'), constant('IntlDateFormatter::SHORT')) }}`

I get the error: "Variable "date_time_object" does not exist". I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change date_time_object by "now" ^^